# I have to delete the product from the database of mongodb by nodejs and javascript how to do in this case

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, product, referenceerror

I used
`var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`
i also tried with small letter o
`var objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`
Also tried

```
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
```

And to Delete my product (from database) i wrote a function

```
deleteProduct:(prodId)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            console.log(prodId)
            console.log(objectId(prodId))
            db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).removeOne({_id:ObjectId(prodId)}).then((response)=>{
                resolve(response)
            })
        })
    }
```

and i wrote a router

```
router.get('/delete-product/:id',(req,res)=>{
    let proId=req.params.id
    console.log(proId)
    productHelpers.deleteProduct(proId).then((response)=>{
      res.redirect('/admin/')
  
    })
})
```

but it shows the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: objectId is not a function
```

Comment: You define the var with uppercase "O", but use it with a lowercase "o".

Comment: i also tried ```var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;```

Comment: I believe ObjectID is a constructor, so use it as: `new ObjectID(prodId)`

Comment: try this `var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;`

Comment: You call objectId twice in `deleteProduct`, once with lower case 'o' and once with upper case.